# How to update an object's property which itself is an array objects in angular (mongoose)

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack, yeoman-generator-angular

This is a part of my schema:

```
var IdeaSchema = new Schema({
  ratings: [{rater: String, star: Number}]
```

And i am trying to add a rating to the ratings array like this:

```
$http.put('/api/ideas/' + idea._id, {ratings: [{rater: 'John', star: 5}] });
```

After the first put, the newer ratings overwrite the array, and i always have the latest rating in it. I tried the suggested extend ([this is the main issue i think](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/310)) instead of merge but it does not seem to work.. I am not sure if i call the api with the correct syntax at all regarding the parameter ratings. And my update method is the yeoman (**generator-angular-fullstack**) generated one:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  ...
  var updated = _.merge(idea, req.body);
  updated.save(function (err) {
    ..
    return res.json(200, idea);
  });
```

**Edit:**

I have made it by changing the api with this one:

```
$http.put('/api/ideas/' + idea._id + '/ratings', {rater: 'John', star: 5} );
```

I can now tell exactly what i want to update. So it is the ratings array of my idea. And a new method in controller:

```
router.put('/:id/ratings', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.addRating);

exports.addRating = function(req, res) {
  ...
    idea.ratings.push(req.body);
    idea.save(function (err) {
      ...
  });
};
```

I am suspicious if this would be the best approach to achieve this anyway. Maybe a better api or a better function would handle this with the generated classic update method.

Comment: I think you can use $push and $pull here

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this.

```
return Promise.cast(Idea.findOne({_id: idea._id, 'ratings.rater': rating.name}).exec())
.then(function(d){
    if (d) {
      return Promise.cast(Idea.update({_id: idea._id, 'ratings.rater': rating.name}, {$set : {'ratings.$' : rating}}).exec());
    } else {
      return Promise.cast(Idea.update({_id: idea._id, 'ratings.rater': {$nin : [rating.name]}}, {$push : {ratings : rating}}).exec());
    }
});
```

So it will search if John's rating is already in there and do `$push` or `$set` correspondingly.